# Configure Spring-Hateoas in a Spring-Data-Rest application for non Rest components

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

spring-data-rest appears to configure spring-hateoas only for its own object-mapper. As a result during other operations (stream-messages, other controllers not managed by data-rest) do not have access to an object with hateoas.

What can i do to activate spring-hateoas for these parts? @EnableHypermediaSupport does not appear to do anything.